# Snapping an unselected face to a different objects edge by moving vertices

Tags: modeling, snapping

I am 'building' a house in blender and currently struggle with the rooftop. I have fixed the very top of the roof and now want to 'snap' the roof both roof parts to the wall below.  I try this by moving some vertices and I want to snap a face connected to these vertices to another objects (the wall) top edge.

This is the roof and the top floor, I want to snap the section marked on the left.

[image: view of the roof]

I select the outward facing part of the roof (4 vertices, 1 face) and want to move them down until the face snaps to the edge noted by the circle.

[image: detailed view of the section]

Comment: Afaik, all snapping tools in Blender can only snap the selection to other elements (vertices, edges, faces), so it is not possible. To get those two shapes perfectly stick, you could use a physics simulation (but it is not a transformation tool, anyway). I could show you a workaround in an answer, if needed, but works differently than you asked.

Comment: Yes please.  I was expecting that Blender does not support this using snapping ... so any best practice on how to do this is appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry I replicated my workflow today, as I did the other day, and then wrote an answer, but then I played with it again, and... it didn't work anymore... maybe it works only in some cases, but I'm not sure. I'll add an answer when I'm absolutely sure that it works... in the meanwhile, yes, Blender could get much ebetter snap tools :)

Comment: I played a bit more. here is what i get: you can get the face to snap to a point or edge on the horizontal "plane", using rotation, pivoting upper corner of the rotating shape. Is not exactly what you asked but works perfectly - until - you apply that rotation. Yes, after applying rotation, it doesn't work anymore... it snaps badly and you can't get a precise snap.  It may be a bug or not, I just wished to put my findings here.